# How to split data based on header(specific format) info using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I need to print the data by splitting the input file based on header info.
My input file looks like

```
1S62DI          00002961143
BITS 
KOOLVISFILET 
KOKOSMELK 
PAPRIKA 
1S62DI          00002961168
BLEEKMIDDEL
SNIJBLOEMEN
ROOIBOSTHEE 
1S62DI          000029611234
SNIJBLOEMEN 
MOZZARELLA 
2SCHENKSTROOP 
ISVUILZAKKEN 
1S62DI          00002961253
BLEEKMIDDEL 
IJBLOEMEN 
PRIKAMIX 
IT  GRANEN 
ROOIBOSTHEE
```

Considering **1S62DI** as my header, I have to extract data till the next occurrence of **1S62DI** and append the sub-string of my header row. Final output should be like

```
BITS  2961143
KOOLVISFILET 2961143
KOKOSMELK 2961143
PAPRIKA 2961143
BLEEKMIDDEL 2961168
SNIJBLOEMEN 2961168
ROOIBOSTHEE 2961168
SNIJBLOEMEN 29611234
MOZZARELLA 29611234
2SCHENKSTROOP 29611234
ISVUILZAKKEN 29611234
BLEEKMIDDEL 2961253
IJBLOEMEN 2961253
PRIKAMIX 2961253
IT  GRANEN 2961253
ROOIBOSTHEE 2961253
```

I tried

```
sed  '/^1S62DI/,/^1S62DI/{/^1S62DI/d; /^1S62DI/d; p;}' file_name
```

just to extract the data between, but not getting the correct result.

EDIT 1:
The input file is a position based file. If the columns have data it will print else it prints nothing. So the complete example would be as below

```
1S62DI          00002961143
BITS 
KOOLVISFILET 
KOKOSMELK 
PAPRIKA 
1S62DI          00002962158
ROOIBOSTHEE                                 0000000800000007120  
ITABROODJES                                 0000000610000004209  0000028
CHENKSTROOP            [2.19]               0000000210000001869  
UISVUILZAKKEN                               0000001080000012852  
1S62DI          00002964138
BLEEKMIDDEL                                 0000001890000006615  0000035
SNIJBLOEMEN            [0.35]               0000000980000021462  0000219
PAPRIKAMIX                                  0000000030000000387  
MUESLIREPEN                                 0000000050000000495  0000099
1S62DI          00002965128
ROOMYOGHURT            [0.25]               0000001260000003150  0000025
BLEEKMIDDEL                                 0000000390000001365  0000035
NIJBLOEMEN             [2.19]               0000000530000011607
```

EDIT 2:
Updated the required output, after extraction, I need to append the last 7 digits of my header data to each row.

```
BITS 2961143 
KOOLVISFILET 2961143
KOKOSMELK 2961143
PAPRIKA 2961143
ROOIBOSTHEE                                 0000000800000007120  2962158
ITABROODJES                                 0000000610000004209  0000028 2962158
CHENKSTROOP            [2.19]               0000000210000001869  2962158
UISVUILZAKKEN                               0000001080000012852  2962158
BLEEKMIDDEL                                 0000001890000006615  0000035 2964138
SNIJBLOEMEN            [0.35]               0000000980000021462  0000219 2964138
PAPRIKAMIX                                  0000000030000000387  2964138
MUESLIREPEN                                 0000000050000000495  0000099 2964138
ROOMYOGHURT            [0.25]               0000001260000003150  0000025 2965128
BLEEKMIDDEL                                 0000000390000001365  0000035 2965128
NIJBLOEMEN             [2.19]               0000000530000011607  2965128
```

Comment: It is not very clear how `00002961143` becomes `261143`.

Comment: How do you know when a line is a "header"? For example, you can't just use "a line with 2 words". Is the header line tab separated, or does it have some special formatting?

Comment: @fedorqui : Header data is always fixed position and fixed size, so I will get a substring based on position.

Comment: @glennjackman : header line always contains "1S62DI" as starting characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sed program. I'd use awk though.

```
sed -n '/^1S62DI[[:blank:]]\+0*/ {s///; h; n}; /^1S62DI/! {G; s/\n/ /; p}' file
```

With commentary (as all moderately complex sed programs require)

```
sed -n '
    /^1S62DI[[:blank:]]\+0*/ {  # lines matching the header
        s///                    # remove the header word, spaces and leading zeros
        h                       # save remaining text in hold space
        n                       # next line
    }
    /^1S62DI/! {                # lines NOT matching the header
        G                       # append a newline and the hold space
        s/\n/ /                 # translate newline to space
        p                       # and print
    }
' file
```

Comment: As per my question its properly extracting the data between the headers and deleting the header. Thank you, I will try to append the header info(last 7 digits) to rows. If you have any suggestions pls let me know.

Answer (score 3):

For multiline things, it is best to use `awk`. For example like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NF==2 {code=$2; next} {print $1, code}' a
BITS    00002961143
KOOLVISFILET    00002961143
KOKOSMELK   00002961143
PAPRIKA     00002961143
BLEEKMIDDEL 00002961168
SNIJBLOEMEN 00002961168
ROOIBOSTHEE     00002961168
SNIJBLOEMEN     000029611234
MOZZARELLA  000029611234
2SCHENKSTROOP   000029611234
ISVUILZAKKEN    000029611234
BLEEKMIDDEL     00002961253
IJBLOEMEN   00002961253
PRIKAMIX    00002961253
IT  GRANEN  00002961253
ROOIBOSTHEE     00002961253
```

This assumes your data is tab-separated. Whenever there are two columns, it stores the 2nd value as code. Then, it keeps printing the single-columned records appending the stored code.

If you want to remove the leading `0`s, just say `+0` so that `awk` casts the string into integer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NF==2 {code=$2+0; next} {print $1, code}' a
BITS    2961143
...
```

---

However, since the rows may have more than one column, let's use glenn jackmans's suggestion in comments and get the code for those lines starting with `1S62DI`:

```
awk -v header="1S62DI" '$1==header {value=$2+0; next}; {print $0, value}' file
```

Comment: This works for part of my input file. Input file my contain more columns in the data, however header data remains same

Comment: @Abhinay could you then update your question with a more representative [mcve]?

Comment: @fedorqui, since there's a specific string for the header, this may be more appropriate: `awk -v header="1S62DI" '$1 == header {value = $2 + 0; next}; {print $0, value}' file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^1S62DI[^1-9]*//;Ta;h;d;:a;G;s/\n/ /' file
```

Remove the unwanted strings from the header line and save the remainder in the hold space (HS) then delete the line. If it was not a header line i.e. the substitution failed, append the HS to the pattern space (PS) (this introduces a newline separating the strings from the PS and the HS) and replace this newline with a space and print.